# How to retrieve random values corresponding to the name in json

Tags: jquery, json, sorting, merge, duplicates

These are the key/values in JSON

```
[  
    {  
      "country":"First",
      "coupon":["1"]
    },
    {  
      "country":"First",
      "coupon":["10"]
    },
    {  
      "country":"First",
      "coupon":["12"]
    },
    {  
      "country":"Second",
      "coupon":"2"
    },
    {  
      "country":"third",
      "coupon":"3"
    },
    {  
      "country":"fourth",
      "coupon":"4"
    },
    {  
      "country":"fifth",
      "coupon":"5"
    }
  ]
```

I sorted out the duplicates in JSON and displayed on dropdown

```
 var sortedCountries = [];
     if (sortedCountries.indexOf(value.country) == -1) {
$('#sel').append('<option value="' + value.coupon + '">' + value.country + '</option>');
          sortedCountries.push(value.country);
}
```

So when I select each option in the dropdown the corresponding value i.e coupon appears. But I need to generate random values (coupons) when I select the dropdown with "country": "First", How to do that?

Comment: could you change the JSON feed to have the dublicated entries as a list? like `"coupon":["1","10","12"]` ? i Mean, they are already an array, so why not put them together and grab a random value out of that array?

Comment: @Stender Thanks for the suggestion.No i can't. Actually i had converted a csv to JSON and had passed those values to dropdown.My JSON is in above mentioned format. What i did is i sorted the duplicate name and only 1 shows in the dropdown ignoring the other two. And what i need is to show the values from the ignored names that are duplicate.

Comment: @Stender To be more specific kindly take a look at this link http://www.thegameappstudio.com/thegasfitness.html .I would like to show only one country name in dropdown with multiple values that generate random on selection.

Comment: I clearly see the same country multiple times though. but I guess you could create your own array from the JSON feed, where the country is key and the coupons value is pushed to that key in the array - that way you would only have the country one time, as it is key, but could have an array of values of which you could get a random index of. That would be my way of doing it I guess.

Comment: @Stender I understand. But its practically impossible as i have to manually enter 100's of coupon code per country. What i am trying is to simplify the work ;)

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example When you state, '*generate random values (coupons)*', what is this based upon? Random between 0 and 10? Please be more specific.

Comment: @Twisty It's based on this link http://www.thegameappstudio.com/thegasfitness.html

Comment: @GovindNarayan that does not answer my question at all. I'm asking how the random coupon code is create.

Comment: @Twisty Its Alphanumeric

Comment: @GovindNarayan I can see that. Is it in an Array or generated by a script? You need to be more specific and forthcoming if you want assistance.

Comment: @Twisty its in an Array. Like the above code.

Comment: @GovindNarayan so when the User selects an Option, you want it to select a specific Coupon Code from the Array of codes and display it, is this right? Or do you want it to randomly select a coupon code from the array?

Comment: @Twisty When an User selects an Option, i want it to select Random Coupon code that matches the key (Country) and display.

Comment: @Stender Could you share the code like the way you suggested ?

Comment: @Twisty i gone through your answer.It doesn't work.

Comment: @Stender Are you online ?

Comment: @Twisty I have posted new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62321623/how-to-show-random-values-in-textbox-json

Answer (score 0):

When I review the link you referenced, I see:

http://www.thegameappstudio.com/watchface/json/thegasfitness.json

This return JSON data like:

```
[
  {
    "Application Title": "TheGas Fitness",
    "Content ID": "000004891575",
    "country": "Spain",
    "coupon": "S8ZEUXL19GELB5RN",
    "Usable Dates(GMT)": "2020-06-04 00:00",
    "Expiration Date(GMT)": "2020-06-30 00:00",
    "Remaining Days": 27,
    "Coupon Status": "Not Used"
  }
]
```

It uses the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#sel').select2({
    /* Sort data using lowercase comparison */
    sorter: data => data.sort((a, b) => a.text.toLowerCase() > b.text.toLowerCase() ? 0 : -1)
  });
  var url = "http://www.thegameappstudio.com/watchface/json/thegasfitness.json";
  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    var myArray = new Array();
    $.each(data, function(index, value) {
      // APPEND OR INSERT DATA TO SELECT ELEMENT.
      $('#sel').append('<option value="' + value.coupon + '">' + value.country + '</option>');
    });
  });

  // SHOW SELECTED VALUE.
  $('#sel').change(function() {
    var str = $("#sel").val();
    $("#txtName").val(str);
  });

  $("#cpy").click(function(event) {
    var copyText = document.getElementById("txtName");
    copyText.select();
    copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
    document.execCommand("copy");
    alert("Copied Coupon Code: " + copyText.value);
  });
});
```

So the resulting Select is like:

```
<select id="sel">
  <option value="S8ZEUXL19GELB5RN">Spain</option>
</select>
```

Your data is vastly different. In your Data, the value is a integer. So in your `change` callback, you would need to send that as an Index to your Coupon Array.

```
$('#sel').change(function() {
  var i = $("#sel").val();
  $("#txtName").val(coupons[i]);
});
```

You would need an Array of Coupon codes, containing the Alphanumeric coupons.

Comment: $("#txtName").val(coupons[i]); doesn't return a value

Comment: @GovindNarayan as I stated in the post, you need to build the array of `coupons`. You have yet to post an example of code that is enough to be to offer assistance. I had to make a lot of guesses at what might be going on.

Comment: could you tell me how to combine from the values given in the question ? example : "country: "First" coupon:[ "1","2","3"] how to pick one value from this and show in option or text ?

Comment: and there isn't additional code beyond what you stated.

Comment: @GovindNarayan your question does not make any sense. Please edit your post and include as much detail as possible. The more you can provide, the easier it will be to assist.

Comment: To be honest i don't know the better way to ask :) . I have a JSON with hundreds of key value pair with Country and Coupon where the keys are duplicates with unique values.So i sorted duplicate to single unique keys and the multiple values corresponding to that key couldn't be shown at random.They are pretty much like the one i posted in question.And the reference link that you took json from.