# JSON get unique random values from array to text input html and show a text when all values are shown

Tags: html, jquery, arrays, json, random

Here is my option code and text box

```
  <select id="sel" class="form-control input-lg" data-live-search="true">
    <option  value="">-- Select Your Country--</option>
    </select><br/><br/><br/>

<input type = "text" id = "txtName" class="form-control input-lg" />
</div>
```

This is my JSON code

```
[  
    {  
      "country":"First",
      "coupon":["1","10","11"]
    },
    {  
      "country":"Second",
      "coupon":"2"
    },
    {  
      "country":"third",
      "coupon":"3"
    },
    {  
      "country":"fourth",
      "coupon":"4"
    },
    {  
      "country":"fifth",
      "coupon":"5"
    }
  ]
```

i have populated JSON to dropdown and shown to text (input) box

```
$('#sel').append('<option value="' + value.coupon + '">' + value.country + '</option>');

        $('#sel').change(function () {
var str = $("#sel").val();
        $("#txtName").val(str);
}
```

What i need is when i select the value "First" in dropdown which has 3 numbers ["1","10","11"]
i need to show either "1" or "10" or "11" at a time in text box randomly.Also the values in the textbox must be unique on each search and when all numbers are shown it must display a text message "No Coupon" in text box.

I used below code to randomly generate it but i couldn't get desired result.Could anyone help me ?

```
Array.prototype.random = function (length) {
       return this[Math.floor((Math.random()*length))];
 }
// var randomcoupon = value.coupon.random(value.coupon.length);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to keep a reference of the list (`firstCouponOptions` as in the below mentioned code) and each time a random value is fetched from `firstCouponOptions` show it in the "text box" and remove the value from the `firstCouponOptions` list at the same time. When it is empty, show "No coupon" message.

```js
const options = [
  { "country": "First", "coupon": ["1", "10", "11"] },
  { "country": "Second", "coupon": "2" },
  { "country": "third", "coupon": "3" },
  { "country": "fourth", "coupon": "4" },
  { "country": "fifth", "coupon": "5" }
];

function getRandomValueFromList(list) {
  const randomeIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (list.length));
  return list[randomeIndex];
}

$(function() {
  const firstCouponOptions = options[0].coupon;
  options.forEach((value) => {
    $('#sel')
      .append('<option value="' + value.coupon + '">' + value.country + '</option>');
  });

  $('#sel').change(function() {
    let str = $("#sel").val();
    if ($("#sel option:selected").text() === 'First') {
      if (firstCouponOptions.length) {
        str = getRandomValueFromList(firstCouponOptions);
        firstCouponOptions.splice(firstCouponOptions.indexOf(str), 1);
      } else {
        str = "No Coupon";
      }
    }
    console.log(str);
    $("#txtName").val(str);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sel" class="form-control input-lg" data-live-search="true">
  <option value="">-- Select Your Country--</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="txtName" class="form-control input-lg" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But what i need is when an user selects "First" it must return only one random value to the text box.

Comment: Thank you :) .If possible please take a look at this link too and go through the comments.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62284591/how-to-retrieve-random-values-corresponding-to-the-name-in-json

Comment: I used your principle to generate random numbers using my old code and it works. Thank you :) and i have marked it and up voted.One more thing how to get a random unique value ? the number must not repeat . You don't have to edit on answer,just let me know on comment and also take a look at that link ;)

Comment: For unique value you should store the last entered value from the list...and before passing the list to `getRandomValueFromList ` remove it from the list.

Comment: You need to update your question for that...Cannot add in comment.

Comment: Done :) and also it must display a text message in box when there are no coupons left.I have updated those in question

Comment: Thank you .What if the Json is dynamic ?

Comment: You need to figure that out based on your json...basic logic would be the same as is mentioned in this answer.

Comment: Okay Thank you very much :)

Comment: This is how i pass Json ```var url = "code.json";


            $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
                var myArray = new Array();
                //avoid duplicates
                          var sortedCountries = [];
                         
                $.each(data, function (index, value) {``` i can't get first value on text

Comment: Do you know how to save the state in browser and if any new user loads the json must return no coupon here is new question for that ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62345580/json-delete-key-value-from-json-and-show-remaining-json-key-value-after-refreshi